# Click evnt trigger parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in a function which triggers a click:

```
$(item).trigger("click", ["fromAll"]);
```

The click function is as below:

```
 $("input.industry").on("click", function (e, fromAll) {
  //Some working
 })
```

When triggering the click from the function I am getting the fromAll as undefined.  Any help please?

Comment: I believe your error is coming from somewhere else. This fiddle is working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/92z87a1c/. The trigger works fine, but when you actually click on the item, it's going to be undefined since "fromAll" is not part of the click event parameters.

Comment: @VVV : it is working on the fiddle but not in my app.  Is there any other way of passing a parameter?

Comment: @VVV : i am using version 3.4.1 of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/0) as follows:

```js
$("input.industry").on("click", function(e, fromAll) {
  if (!fromAll)
    console.log($(this).data("fromAll"));
  else
    console.log(fromAll);
}).data("fromAll", "fromAll");

$("input.industry").trigger("click", ["fromAllTrigger"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="industry" value="" />
```